# React resend request to server on page reload

Tags: reactjs, request, state, refresh

I have a table the gets a data using Fetch requests,everything works fine and the code is implemented using react hooks and function,the problem is when the user hits "F5" and refresh the page all the data is removed and I don't know how to detect the refresh and resend the request to the servers,If there a way to fetch the request again on page refresh using react functions/hooks?
by the way I am a beginner to react any help is appreciated

```
/*Libraries*/
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Avatar from "../Avatar";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
const source = "/images/logo.png";
/*******************************************************************************************************/
export default function Info(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);
  var toke = "Token " + props.token + " ";
  var url = "server";
  var url2 = "server/update";

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", Authorization: toke },
  };

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(url, requestOptions).catch((error) =>
      console.error(error)
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    const items = await data.json();
    setItems(items);
    setStatus(data.status);
  };

  if (status == "200") {
    return (
      <div class="all">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center" style={styles}>
          <div class="testing" style={styles.testing}></div>

          <h2>Company's Name:{items.company_name}</h2>
          <Avatar avatarUrl={items.logo} />
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Company's Manager: </h3>
              <h6>Name:{items.manager.first_name}</h6>
              <h6>Last Name:{items.manager.second_name}</h6>
              <h6>Phone:{items.manager.phone}</h6>
              <h6>Email:{items.manager.email}</h6>
              <h6>Address:{items.manager.address}</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Deputy Director:</h3>
              <h6>Name:{items.deputy_director.first_name}</h6>
              <h6>Last Name:{items.deputy_director.second_name}</h6>
              <h6>Age:{items.deputy_director.age}</h6>
              <h6>Phone:{items.deputy_director.phone}</h6>
              <h6>Email:{items.deputy_director.email}</h6>
              <h6>Address:{items.deputy_director.address}</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Vehicles:</h3>
              {items.car.map((car, index) => (
                <div>
                  <h6>license number:{car.license_no}</h6>
                  <h6>license due to:{car.license_expiry_date}</h6>
                  <h6>Bituah due to:{car.insurance_expiry_date}</h6>
                  <h6>
                    Bituah till age:[number from 20-70] {car.insurance_age}
                  </h6>
                  <h6>
                    Photo:
                    <Avatar avatarUrl={car.image} />
                  </h6>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          marginTop: "100px",
        }}
      >
        <Loader
          type="Puff"
          color="#343a40"
          height={150}
          width={150}
          timeout={3000} //3 secs
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put your fetch method into an useEffect, then the data request should to send for the server on every refresh.

```
useEffect(() => fetch(), [])
```

But if you share your code we can be smarter.

Comment: I am using the useEffect to fetch the data but it is stll not working.

Comment: I think you got 200 before the data and you dont have a re-render.

Comment: Lets see.  Try this first: const unsubscribe = fetchItems() and below this: return unsubscribe, cause if you put an async method into useeffect you should clean it up.

Comment: It did fix the issue with resend the fetch request when refreshing the page,thank you!.

Comment: But now it is giving me problems by removing the token stored in the props when refreshing the page...

Comment: if you dont use the token in the parent component you can generate in this Info component.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if we have your code

Comment: Yeah you are right,I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer,useEffect was indeed resending the request on refresh,but the problem is my request require a token passed from the props,and useffect only update the probs after some seconds,so my solution was simply using the useEffect when props are loaded.thanks for everyone for helping me understand useEffect better,the fix was:

```
     useEffect(() => {
     if(props.token){fetchItems()}
  }, [props.token]);
```